# How to edit video in this stituation? Trim or overlay?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am a newbie. It's really hard for me when want to edit video like as I want so I open a thread and need your help. Thank you.

Original video seperate ordinarily (every second):        1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 v.v...
and I want to edit it into new video with new ordinarily: 1 4 3 6 5 8 7 10 (keep 1,3,5 and edit 2,4,6 become 4,6,8 then loop)

Please help me. I search about overlay but really dont know how to use.
How can I do this by ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

blend, add video twice, second file with offset 2 sec:

```
#!/bin/bash
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i test04.mkv -ss 2 -i test04.mkv -filter_complex "
[0][1]blend='all_expr=if(mod(trunc(T),2),A,B)'[v];
[0]volume=0:enable='mod(trunc(t+1),2)'[a0];
[1]volume=0:enable='mod(trunc(t),2)'[a1];
[a0][a1]amix[a]
" -map [v] -map [a] -c:v huffyuv -c:a pcm_s16le -f matroska - | ffplay -autoexit -
```

with test source:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -f lavfi -re -i testsrc -ss 2 -f lavfi -re -i testsrc -filter_complex "
[0][1]blend='all_expr=if(mod(trunc(T),2),A,B)'[v]
" -map [v] -c:v huffyuv -f matroska - | ffplay -autoexit -
```

this code makes sequence: 2 1 4 3 6 5 8 7 10 9

change [expression](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Expression-Evaluation) for your needs, this `if(mod(trunc(T),2),A,B)`
where `T` is time, `A` and `B` is streams to switch.

Comment: Thanks for your help. And if odinarily is every 3 seconds, how do I edit code? For example: 123 456 789 101112 131415 => 123 101112 789 .....

Comment: I just test and it is not same as I want :(

Comment: I just test and it is not same as I want :(
Your code convert video like this

Original    1  2 3 4 5 6 7      8
Convert    1 2 1 4 3 6      5      8

not same as I want:

Original    1  2 3 4 5 6 7
Convert    1 4 3 6 5 8      7

Comment: ah, yes. maybe instead of -itsoffset 2, use -ss 2

Answer (score 0):

Use select and overlay filters.

`ffmpeg -i in -filter_complex "split=2[main][top];[top]setpts=PTS-2/TB,trim=0[top];[main][top]overlay=enable='mod(floor(t)\,2)'" out.`

If you have audio as well,

`ffmpeg -i in -filter_complex "split=2[mainv][shiftv];[shiftv]setpts=PTS-2/TB,trim=0[shiftv];[mainv][shiftv]overlay=enable='mod(floor(t)\,2)';asplit=2[maina][shifta];[shifta]asetpts=PTS-2/TB,atrim=0,volume=0:enable='mod(floor(t+1)\,2)'[shifta];[maina]volume=0:enable='mod(floor(t)\,2)'[maina];[maina][shifta]amix=duration=first,volume=2" out.`

Comment: Really thanks for all of you who take time to care for a newbie like me. Thank you.